# What is the difference between Stream transform and listen in flutter? When to implement them?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am learning BLoC pattern in Flutter without using any package. What I know is data are sent as Sink and output is given as Stream in BLoC pattern. StreamController is there to handle these thing. Looks like both method make changes to the input data but I am confused about their purpose. Went through the documentation but couldn't understand.

```
Class CartBloc{
    final _cart = Cart();

    Sink<Product> get addition => _additionalController.sink;

    final _additionController = StreamController<Product>();

    Stream<int> get itemCount => _itemCountSubject.stream;

    final _itemCountSubject = BehaviorSubject<int>();

    CartBloc(){
        _additionaController.stream.listen(_handle);
    }

    void _handle(Product product){
        _cart.add(product);
        _itemCountSubject.add(_cart.itemCount);
    }
}
```

Above code is from **Build reactive mobile apps with Flutter (Google I/O '18)**. They mentioned listen is necessary because we are not just capturing data but doing some other operation through the **_handle()** method. Now my question is can't we implement same with **stream.transform()**. If yes what will be the equivalent implementation and if no what is the reason.

Answer (score 1):

`stream.transform(transformer)` will create a new stream that is somehow modified from the original. It does *not* start listening on the stream, and so no values will flow through the stream until it has a listener.

Think of `transform` as a way to *change* a stream, usually for some other bit of code to listen to. Think of `listen` as a way to react to values that come through a stream.

Comment: but without listen, how transform gets data from view? Listening is not mandatory in BLoC?  because I saw some tutorial where they didnt use listen but only transform. No listen mean they didnt even create constructor.

Comment: Something must be listening to the stream somewhere, it doesn't need to happen in the same place as the transformer is added.